# Material UI Select React.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

It is possible that we can change the behavior of the dropdown in Material UI Select? I want to change the behavior of `<ul>` where it should not look like a pop-up.

What I want to happen is the `<li>` will encapsulate the selected `<ul>`
Just like what the 2nd picture attached below:

This is the current Select Component of Material UI
 [image]

What I want to achieve is something like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```html
<FormControl
  variant="outlined"
  className={clsx(
    classes.formControl,
    success && classes.success,
    danger && classes.danger
  )}
  required={isRequired}
>
  <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    value={value}
    onChange={e => handleOnChange(e)}
    // MenuProps={{ classes: { paper: classes.dropdownPaper }}}
    label={label}
    name={name}
    MenuProps={{
      classes: { paper: classes.dropdownPaper },
      anchorOrigin: {
        vertical: "bottom",
        horizontal: "left"
      },
      getContentAnchorEl: null
    }}
  >
    {options.map((opt, index) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem value={opt.value} key={index}>
          {opt.text}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    })}
  </Select>
</FormControl>;
```

Comment: So you want to change the options' hover background color am I right?

Comment: @keikai nope, the whole style of the dropdown of select. Please check my post again, I updated it, the first pic is the current select component of material UI, and what I want to achieve is the second picture.

Comment: So you mean the `border`, `font`, `padding`, and the `options' hover background color`? Have you achieved some of them? Can you provide an online demo?

Comment: @keikai what the latest I achieved was on the first pic, I don't think we can change the container of dropdown in the select which the container of dropdown like the ul, li is Paper component.

Comment: nothing to do with react

Comment: @Deryck Well, I hardly agree with you, in this post, Material-UI styles solution is related to React. If you check their document or check the questions under the Material-UI tag, you would find out that they are tightly bound.

Comment: @Deryck And it's a good question, although the poster seems to need to make more focus on it. I don't want it to be exposed less, so sorry but I will roll back the react tag.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

What I would do is rather than searching in the textfield component section you need to go to the menu components section and search for the selected menu component or customized menu component is which the items pop right above the button here is a link: https://material-ui.com/components/menus/

you can also customize the "split button component" as it already has what you are looking for built in, the only thing you need to customize the color. here is a link to the button component the ""split button" is at the bottom of the page.
https://material-ui.com/components/button-group/

Hope this helps.